# OutOfMemoryError in ToolTwist Controller during install

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, tooltwist

While installing my project using the Controller, I got the following error.

```
Starting transmission...
  Bundle 1 (4kb = 1 installs, 23 deletes)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at tooltwist.fip.FipBatchOfUpdates.<init>(FipBatchOfUpdates.java:50)
    at tooltwist.fip.FipServer.source_getRequestedUpdates(FipServer.java:214)
    at tooltwist.fip.FipThisMachineServerProxy.askForUpdates(FipThisMachineServerProxy.java:53)
    at tooltwist.fip.Fip.processUpdatesAndDeletes(Fip.java:493)
    at tooltwist.fip.Fip.installFiles(Fip.java:352)
    at tooltwist.controller.util.InstallerUtil.install(InstallerUtil.java:376)
    at tooltwist.controller.util.InstallerUtil.main(InstallerUtil.java:57)

Sorry, the install failed.

Finished with status false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a very large project, you might need to increase the default value for JAVA_OPTS in extension-projects/ttc_t/config/bin/installLaunchpad. The default is 256mb, but you can increase according to your needs. The Controller uses FIP which doesn't need memory in proportion to the project being deployed, so a modest increase should work fine.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=32m"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had same thought and I just don't know where to configure it. Just get confused on extension-projects/ttc_t which actually mean devel/ttc_t.